# Software Updater fails to fetch and download

Tags: updates, update-manager, software-updater

I am totally new to Ubuntu and even though that I have some problems with it I like it a lot. And in the previous version I did solve quite some problems and I was happy that I could. But in 12.10 this is bugging me so much. I looked everywhere I just don't know why I get this error, actually errors:

```
W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 12.10 _Quantal Quetzal_ - Release amd64 (20121017.5)/dists/quantal/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
, W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 12.10 _Quantal Quetzal_ - Release amd64 (20121017.5)/dists/quantal/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
, W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 12.10 _Quantal Quetzal_ - Release amd64 (20121017.5)/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
, W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 12.10 _Quantal Quetzal_ - Release amd64 (20121017.5)/dists/quantal/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
, W:Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/commercial-ppa-uploaders/skype/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.191 80]
, W:Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/commercial-ppa-uploaders/skype/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.191 80]
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have absolutely no idea what else to try. Can somebody please help me?